# How to use instead of delete trigger and still delete the row in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, triggers, sql-delete

I am trying to delete a row from a table in my database, but first I have to delete rows that correspond with that row via foreign keys.

I am using an `instead of` trigger on the main table and inside of it, I am first deleting child rows from other tables that correspond to that main row, and then I want to delete the main row. But (as expected) the main row is not being deleted because it is an `INSTEAD OF` trigger.

If I try to delete the main row in the instead of trigger I am getting error:

> INSTEAD OF triggers do not support direct recursion. The trigger execution failed

If I try to use `AFTER DELETE` trigger, I get error:

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint [...]

because I am trying to delete the row that corresponds with other rows in other tables.

I've been trying to think of an idea to solve this problem, but I'm stuck and I couldn't find a working solution on the Internet. I have a feeling that I'm missing something obvious, but I can't seem to find it.

Thanks and take care guys!

Comment: Is this something that cascading deletes could solve (e.g. you're just deleting dependencies)? Or are you doing other things with the deleted data?

Comment: @ZLK Thanks for the answer! I knew I would facepalm when I hear the answer. It is the solution for me, but if I wanted to do something else with the data before the delete, that would be a different story.

Comment: You also have the option of altering the table to not check the constraint. For example, `alter table X nocheck constraint myConstraintName`, then doing the delete statement / data manipulation (e.g. in an after delete trigger) then turning the constraint back on `alter table X check constraint myConstraintName`.

Comment: You can cascade the deletes yourself. That is, examine the `deleted` table and delete any rows in any child tables yourself from within the trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has been resolved with help of @ZLK using cascading deletes or:

> @ZLK: You also have the option of altering the table to not check the constraint. For example, `alter table X nocheck constraint myConstraintName`, then doing the delete statement / data manipulation (e.g. in an after delete trigger) then turning the constraint back on `alter table X check constraint myConstraintName`